# Just need to bold and touch up scanned signatures and logos

Tags: adobe-photoshop, software-recommendation, font-design

Had a program called SLED from VSsoftware (Aristotle?) that converted vector graphics to fonts.  It had a very basic editing program to crop, scale, bold check signatures and logos (all b&w) and could accomplish very quickly a few minutes.  Nothing fancy.  I believe the company has gone out of business (we've had the program since early 90's) but the dinosaur computer and parallel port scanner it was on has moved on to better places.

I'm looking for something similar but not finding anything and in looking at various products as possible replacements it appears to be way overkill.

Does anybody have any ideas.  The steps I've seen in Adobe Photoshop or Gimp look daunting.

Comment: You're asking for a software that converts vectors to fonts or one to edit scanned documents? Your question is a bit confusing, would you mind [editing to make it more clear](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/73779/edit)?

Answer (score 1):

This is my first answer here on this forum, so hopefully it will be useful.

I don't see why this should be too difficult in Photoshop.  I tried this with a faded signature and the result was good. First I made levels adjustment layer to increase the contrast, then applied a black and white adjustment layer to get rid of the colours, then an exposure adjustment layer to make the image brighter. Then made a new layer from visible, by clicking CTRL+Alt+Shift+E, then I finished off by using a white brush to clean up.

[image: scanned signature processing]

Answer (score 0):

The best website online that transforms vector graphics to icon fonts is [IcoMoon App](https://icomoon.io), a great site with tons of features, which keeps track of your fonts and has features like metadata, css stylesheets, versioning and support for IE. Other websites I recommend are [Fontstruct](http://fontstruct.com/) and [Fontastic](http://fontastic.me/). You can edit fonts on both.